# pySpark compute max of multiple columns while ignoring NaN

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aggregate

I'm trying to compute the max (or any agg function) for multiple columns in a pyspark dataframe. However, since these columns have some NaNs, the result for the max aggregator is always NaN. Is there any way to ignore NaN while making this computation?

Here's the code that I'm running:

```
panel = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [2,3,4,np.nan],
                         'col2': [1,np.nan,4,np.nan],
                         'col3': [2,7,1,np.nan],
                         'col4': [np.nan,3,4,np.nan]})
sq = context.sql
sparkDF = sq.createDataFrame(panel) 

# Compute max
mapp = {c: 'max' for c in panel.columns} # {'col1': 'max', col2': 'max', ...}
vals = panel.agg(mapp).collect()[0]
print(vals)
```

PS: I can't just drop rows containing a NaN, because other columns might have a valid value.
I would also want to avoid having to iterate over every column and computing the max value 'manually', as it would result in a big performance impact.

Comment: What does `mapping` do here?  the number is higher than any values in original dataframe, so max would be the value of `mapping` if you fill values with `mapping`.

Comment: My bad, copied the wrong function. Ive updated the last part of the code where i compute the max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `max` with `fill`.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
sparkDF = sparkDF.na.fill(0).select([F.max(x).alias(f'max_{x}') for x in sparkDF.columns])

sparkDF.show()

# +--------+--------+--------+--------+
# |max_col1|max_col2|max_col3|max_col4|
# +--------+--------+--------+--------+
# |     4.0|     4.0|     7.0|     4.0|
# +--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

====================================================

Update:

For calculating average with ignoring NaN, you cannot use the regular `avg` as this includes NaNs. In order to calculate average by dropping NaN, you can use `sum` and `count` with a condition.

```py
sparkDF = sparkDF.select([
    (F.sum(F.when(~F.isnan(x), F.col(x))) / F.count(F.when(~F.isnan(x), True))).alias(f'avg_{x}')
    for x in sparkDF.columns
])
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! This would be a problem if my max value is a negative value though, but that can be changed by changing the '0' to a very negative value. In the case i want to compute the average, how would you do it? In that case i wouldnt want to consider these NaNs in my computation, as it would skew the result.

Comment: do you mean `avg([1, nan, 4, nan]) = (1+4) / 2 = 2.5`  or `(1+4) / 4 = 1.25`?

Comment: The first one. I'm asking because if i drop nans from a specific column, i would lose the entire row, which means losing a possible valid value in another column